How did Schrödinger interpret the wave function before Born's probability rule?
In 1926, Schrödinger published his wave equation, introducing a new way to describe quantum systems. Later that same year, Max Born proposed the probability interpretation, suggesting that the wave function’s squared amplitude, $|\psi|^2$ gives the probability of finding a particle in a specific location. Since my understanding of the wave function relies heavily on Born's rule, I'm unclear on how Schrödinger originally viewed it before Born’s interpretation came into play.
How did Schrödinger interpret the wave function when he first introduced his equation, given that the probabilistic view was only proposed later by Born?

I recommend HSM.

Resource: article by Ricardo Karam 'Schrödinger’s original struggles with a complex wave function' (2020). Also available: youtube video with presentation by Ricardo Karam:  Schrödinger’s Struggles with a Complex Wave Function If this question is posted on HSM then on HSM I will expand this comment to an answer.

Erwin Schrödinger, starting from de Broglie's particle wave assumption, invented the Wave Mechanics form of Quantum Mechanics. He made the first calculation of the hydrogen atom showing that Bohr's artificial quantization conditions can be explained by the solution of an eigenvalue problem of a differential equation, of his Schrödinger wave equation. He was, of course, interested in a physical interpretation of the complex wave function. Thus he considered, only heuristically, an interpretation of $\psi \psi^*$ of the single electron wave function as the distributed charge density of an electron. Calculated intensities and polarizations of emitted light based on this picture agreed surprisingly well with experimental results. But this charge density interpretation ran into problems for multi-electron systems. Even though he also found a way for a charge interpretation in this case he eventually accepted Born's probability interpretation. See a detailed description in E. Schrödinger "Collected Papers on Wave Mechanics ", Blackie & Son Ltd., London and Glasgow 1928.
PS: It is interesting that this "wrong" charge density interpretation of the wave function is nowadays extensively used in chemistry. Even the 1998 Chemistry Nobel prize awarded to Walter Kohn for his famous "Density Functional Theory" Wikipedia uses this concept. So after all, the charge density interpretation is rather useful and not so far from the truth. See also PSE and ArXiv

Actually, Pauli had calculated the Hydrogen spectrum in the matrix “reinerpretation” before that…

An english translation of that epochal paper, bypassing the ODEs and complexities of the subsequent Schroedinger paper. Pure operator "Umdeutung"!

My sense is the OP was seeking your last ref discussion contrasted to the Hitachi experiment.

@Cosmas Zachos You are right. Pauli's impressive paper was received by Zeitschrift für Physik on 17 January 1926, and Schrödinger's in Annalen der Physik on 27 January 1926. However, Pauli's paper was published only on 1 May 1926, Schrödinger's on 13 March 1926.  In the end, which was first doesn't really matter because the theories were developed independently from completely different starting points.

Lets take a electron.Schrodinger believed that the charge and mass of the electron were spread in its own cloud, the solution of the wavefunction at one point(x,t) described how much mass and charge it had at that point.Of course for that to work out the integral of the "mass density" and the "charge density" of all points would be equal to the mass and the charge of the electron respectively.

I don’t this is correct.  First, you are basically assuming a probability density for charge (spread over space), which Schrodinger never did, and this is the Born interpretation.  Next,  Schrodinger did not have an interpretation for his wavefunction. He was just happy to get the correct energy levels.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function I remember it correctly.Section "Historical background" 3rd paragraph.

… and I learned something.

Schr's misinterpretation is in section 8 of his PR exposition.

...if only he had access to the Hitachi experiment of 1989, his paragraph would be missing.

Btw I dont believe you are correct.Schrodinger is known for what I have said in the question,what he believed AFTER he had been corrected doesnt matter the OP asks for his initial belief.
